# TypeError: routingState.equals is not a function | Jest test case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

This is my selector.js file:-

```
const makeSelectLocationState = () => {
  let prevRoutingState;
  let prevRoutingStateJS;

  return (state) => {
    const routingState = state.get('route'); // or state.route

    if (!routingState.equals(prevRoutingState)) {
      prevRoutingState = routingState;
      prevRoutingStateJS = routingState.toJS();
    }

    return prevRoutingStateJS;
  };
};
```

and the following test case I have written:-

```
it('makeSelectLocationState function testing', () => {
    const selectLocationState = makeSelectLocationState();
    const mockedState = fromJS({
      route: '',
    });
    expect(selectLocationState(mockedState)).toEqual('');
  });
```

While running the test case using jest I get the following error:-

```
TypeError: routingState.equals is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
const routingState = state.get('route');
```

Sense you didn't get the routingState,possible undefined, so you will get this above error message.**So check the date of routingState.**

And in the test file, pass mockedState to selectLocationState

```
selectLocationState(mockedState)
```

However,makeSelectLocationState function didn't have property.Maybe change to this:

```
const makeSelectLocationState = (state) => {}
```

Comment: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'equals' of undefined.*

After making the changes I get this above error.
@root

Comment: @Shwetank please provide the output of console.log(routingState) in makeSelectLocationState.

Comment: The output of the console.log(routingState) is *Map {size: 1, _root: ArrayMapNode, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}*
@root

Comment: @Shwetank while the type of routingState is Map,and Map actually don't have equals function.You can use this:routingState.toString() === prevRoutingState.toString() or use forEach to check every item of routingState.

Answer (score 0):

```
route: ''
const routingState = state.get('route');
```

It looks like `route` is a string (an empty string). Strings do not have an `equals` method, so `routingState.equals()` doesn't exist.

Perhaps you could set `mockedState.route` to an object that has an `equals` function:

```
const mockedState = fromJS({
  route: { equals: item => item === item },
});
```